# Ansible Connecting to Windows Server 2016

Tags: ansible

I have OpenSSH installed on my 2016 Server, and I can SSH to it from my Linux Ansible host. I am having a problem when I try to connect to the Windows server from Linux. Here is my inventory file:

```
[windows]
10.9.124.12

[windows:vars]
ansible_user=ansible
ansible_shell_type=cmd
```

When I attempt to run ansible -i inventory -m ping all, I get the following error:

`Invalid shell type specified (cmd), or the plugin for that shell type is missing.`

Comment: can you try changing the shell type to `powershell`  from `cmd` ? and `ansible_connection` to `ssh`, see this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#configuring-ansible-for-ssh-on-windows

Comment: I set it to powershell, and that failed as well. I do not recall the exact error. I will try again tomorrow and reply.